# Superimpose pairs plot based on condition

Tags: r, lattice, par

**Edit:**I am sorry, but the situation could be a little bit more complex than I have shown. However, both of your scripts work, although the first might be not so clear for large dataset due to point overlap! Thanks very much Sacha!

I would like to first show the pairs of several variables, and then superimpose the selected data of the same dataset. Usually, the superimpose can be achived using `par(new=T)` like this:

```
h<-rnorm(nc)  # this variable was used for conditioning
x<-rnorm(nc)
y<-rnorm(nc)
z<-rnorm(nc)
m<-cbind(x,y,z)
pairs(m)
par(new=T)
pairs(m[h>0.7,],col="red")
```

However, it seems that the `par()` setting does not work for such usage.

Then, probably lattice library could help, ex. `splom()`, but I do not know if it really works, and how.  Could someone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume `paris` must be `pairs`? The `pairs` function doesn't have an `add` argument or so, it would probably also not be that trivial since the plot has 9 panels (simply doing `points` will plot in the last panel). but it is not that hard to do what you want in a single plot using `col`:

```
nc <- 100
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(nc)
y<-rnorm(nc)
z<-rnorm(nc)
m<-cbind(x,y,z)

cols <- ifelse(x>0.7,"red","black")
pairs(m,col=cols)
```

[image]

## Edit:

Another thing you can do in `pairs` is actually set the function you want to do in each panel. By default this is `points`, but you can extend that to include some conditions:

```
nc <- 100

X<-rnorm(nc)
Y<-rnorm(nc)
Z<-rnorm(nc)
m<-cbind(X,Y,Z)

panelfun <- function(x,y,foo=X,...){
    points(x[foo<0.7],y[foo<0.7],col="black",...)
    points(x[foo>0.7],y[foo>0.7],col="red",...)
}

pairs(m,panel=panelfun)
```

This gives the same picture as before (well different points because I didnt set a seed). Simply making the color vector would be easier to accomplish this, but you can make the panel function as big as you would like.

Also, the `...` allow other arguments to be passed to the `points` function:

```
pairs(m,panel=panelfun,pch=16)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lattice::splom` works fine. The color indexing needs to be boosted by 1 since R indexing is 1 based rather than zero-based and the logical vectors get coerced as 0 and 1.

```
library(lttice)
nc=100; h<-rnorm(nc)  
x<-rnorm(nc)
y<-rnorm(nc)
z<-rnorm(nc)
m<-cbind(x,y,z)
splom(m, col=c("blue", "red")[1+(h>0.7)])
```

[image]