# Adding points to Scatter plot Matrix

Tags: r, plot

I want to add points to my Scatter plot matrix.

```
head(pca)
        pc1       pc2         pc3       pc4       
[1,]  0.72859559 -2.2864943 -0.5408501  0.1564730  
[2,]  0.34852943  0.3100891  0.6007349 -0.5985266  
[3,] -0.04605026  0.5067896 -0.2911211 -1.1617171  
[4,] -1.88358617  1.3739440 -0.5655383  0.9518367  
[5,]  0.35528650 -1.7482304 -0.3871520 -0.7837712
```

I ran  kmeans to my PCA data and I can plot a scatter plot matrix by using the following:

```
k <- kmeans(pca,3)

plot(pca, col=k$clust, pch=16)
```

Next I want to add X's to show the centers by adding

```
+ points(k$centers, col=1:3 ,pch="X", cex=3)
```

but its doesn't work. If I reduce to only 2 PCs then the following plots the centers but only for 2 pcs:

```
plot(pca[,c(1,2)], col=k$clust, pch=16) + points(k$centers, col=1:10 ,pch="X", cex=3)
```

side note when I enter the code above R returns "numeric(0)". What does that mean?

```
  > plot(pca[,c(1,2)], col=k$clust, pch=16) + points(k$centers, col=1:10 ,pch="X", cex=3)
  > numeric(0)
```

the following has been helpful to some degree. [Kmeans clustering identifying knowledge in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572746/kmeans-clustering-identifying-knowledge-in-r)

Comment: You're trying to _add_ plot objects. That works with `ggplot()` but not with base graphics. `numeric(0)` means the number 0, which in this case is R's way of telling you that it doesn't understand why you're adding two plot objects.

Comment: I found this answer also useful. Hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057060/superimpose-pairs-plot-based-on-condition

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "It's not working".  This works fine for me:

```
# parameters
rows <- 100
cols <- 4
groups <- 3

# create a matrix of uniforms
pca <- matrix(runif(rows*cols),ncol = cols,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(pca) <- paste0('pc',seq(cols))

# calculate the kmeans
(k <- kmeans(pca,groups))

# plot the data and the means
plot(pca, col=k$clust, pch=15)
points(k$centers, col=seq(groups),pch="X", cex=3)
```

note that you're only going to get a voronoi tessellation in a 2-d plot when the number of columns (`cols`) in your matrix is 2.

Comment: right. but what I am trying to do is `plot(pca[,c(1,2,3)], col=k$clust, pch=16) points(k$centers, col=1:10 ,pch="X", cex=3)` and that doesn't work .